# Variational bicomplex/jet bundle formalism

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, mathematics, variational-principle, variational-calculus

If we consider a functional

$$J[f] = \int_{a}^{b}\mathcal{L}(x,f(x),f'(x))dx\tag{1}$$

then its functional derivative in the direction of some function $g$ can be defined as

$$\delta J[f][g] = \frac{d}{d\epsilon}\biggr|_{\epsilon = 0}\biggr(\int\mathcal{L}(x, f+\epsilon\delta g, f'+\epsilon\delta g')dx\biggr)\tag{2}$$

How does variational bicomplex/jet bundle formalism provide a more generalized approach to variation of a functional?

Answer (score 1):

> How does variational bicomplex/jet bundle formalism provide a more generalized approach to variation of a functional?

It does not. An approach based on the use of function spaces (via functional analysis or diffeological spaces) will also allow one to treat eg. nonlocal functionals (i.e. those more general than the integral of a finite order Lagrangian) at the cost of having to take into account more details about the particular variation problem.

The approach based on the use of jet bundles is "formal" in nature, i.e. it abstracts away the actual variational problem, therefore things such as function spaces, boundary conditions, even actual functionals don't really appear. It focuses solely on the observation that given a Lagrangian function $\mathcal L(x,y,\dots,y_{(r)})$ depending on a set of independent variables, "dependent variables" and "formal derivatives of the dependent variables w.r.t. the independent ones", there is an operator $$ E_\sigma(\mathcal L)=\sum_{k=0}^r(-1)^kd_{i_1}\dots d_{i_k}\frac{\partial\mathcal L}{\partial y^\sigma_{i_1...i_k}} $$assigning to the Lagrangian its Euler-Lagrange expressions, and this approach makes it possible to study the formal properties of this operator. Another point is that the jet formalism allows for one to study *global* variation problems on a manifold because the formalism is essentially coordinate-free, whereas doing things the "classical way", one needs to piece together local calculations using charts, and unlike in classical tensor calculus, the transformation properties of some objects can be rather complicated.

Comment: That’s a wonderful answer, again. Could you also provide a concrete example as to what a non-local functional might like, and as to how jet bundle formalism roughly treats that?

Comment: @Supergravity Take eg. $S[\phi]=\int dx \int dx^\prime \phi(x)K(x-x^\prime)\phi(x^\prime)$. And the jet formalism *doesn't* handle these.